# SQLAlchemy and setup of Postgresql tables with columns storing arrays of data

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, relationship

I'm working on a project where we have to create a simple database backed API. My project is baseball related, and will store player, team, and player agent data.

My goal is a database with 3 tables: `players`, `teams`, and `agents`. `teams` to `players` is one to many, and `agents` to `players` is one to many. The `players` table has `team_id` and `agent_id` foreign keys linking to each of the other two tables.

Here is where I'm lost. In the `teams` table, I'd like a column storing an array of `player_id`s. Basically, this will be the team roster. In the `agent` table, I'd like a `clients` column to also store an array of `player_id`s, which will be a client list. I'm having trouble implementing this. Do these columns need to be foreign keys referencing `player.id`, or should a team's roster and an agent's client list be broken off into separate tables? Will my idea even work?

Here are my models, with code irrelevant to my question (name, position, location, etc) removed:

```
class Player(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'players'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'),
                        nullable=False)
    agent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('agents.id'),
                         nullable=False)

    team = db.relationship(
        'Team', backref=db.backref('player', cascade='all,delete'))

    agent = db.relationship(
        'Agent', backref=db.backref('player', cascade='all,delete'))
```

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    players = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String), default=[])
```

```
class Agent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'agents'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    clients = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String), default=[])
```

Comment: Not being familiar with baseball, is roster somehow different from the set of players having the team's ID as their `team_id`? In other words, why do you need an array of players? Note that the backrefs already create ORM relationships that are lists of related players.

Comment: No, the roster wouldn’t be different from the players with the same `team_id`. Your question and ORM clarification definitely made me rethink my approach. In my mind, I thought I’d need a `player_id` column in both `teams` and `agents` to show which players belonged to each team or agent. I’ve now realized this is what my query filtered by `id` will accomplish. Thanks again @IljaEverilä, you opened my mind to something simple.